# Auth0-lock won't show up close button angular

Tags: angular, auth0-lock

I have been trying to add auth0-lock widget to my angular application, it works just fine,
yet when it comes to ui customization, the close button won't appear even though i've added option closable: true. here's my code:

```
import {Auth0Lock} from 'auth0-lock'

constructor(private router: Router, private cookie: CookieService, private http: HttpClient){
  this.lock.on("authenticated", (authResult: any) => {
    this.lock.getProfile(authResult.accessToken, async (error: any, profile: any) => {
      if (error) throw new Error('error');
      // code
    });
  });
}
auth0Options = {
  closable: true,
  theme: {
    primaryColor: '#DFA612'
  },
  auth: {
    redirectUrl: environment.auth0.callbackURL,
    responseType: 'token id_token',
    audience: `https://${environment.auth0.domain}/userinfo`,
    params: {
      scope: 'openid profile email'
    }
  },
  autoclose: true
};
lock = new Auth0Lock(
  environment.auth0.clientId,
  environment.auth0.domain,
  this.auth0Options
)
login(){
  this.lock.show()
}
logout(){
  this.lock.logout();
  //code
}
```

Any help please? thank you in advance.

PS: Everything works just fine, my only problem that it's not closable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there was a problem about style, i had to overwrite the close button css class which is `.auth0-lock-close-button` and set its `z-index` to a higher value.